# Failing to display json into html with ajax

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

I am implementing a 'load more' button for my posts.

With ajax this is what I'm doing to display the loaded posts into my html:

```
success:function(res){
                var _html='';
                var json_data=$.parseJSON(res.posts);
                $.each(json_data,function(index,data){
                _html+='<div class="post-box col-md-1">\
                  <div class="info-box mb-4">\
                  <div>\
                    {% if '+data.fields.cantidad+' == 1 %}\
                      <h3>'+data.fields.donador+'</h3><text>te donó '+data.fields.cantidad+' '+data.fields.objeto+'.</text>\
                    {% else %}\
                    <h3>'+data.fields.donador+' </h3><text>te donó '+data.fields.cantidad+' '+data.fields.objeto+'s.</text>\
                    {% endif %}\
                      <br>\
                      <text>'+data.fields.whenpublished+' </text>\
                      {% if '+data.fields.message+' != "" %}\
                      <hr>\
                    <text>'+data.fields.message+'</text>\
                    {% endif %}\
                  </div>\
                  </div>\
              </div>';
                              };
```

This is my model:

```
class Donacion(models.Model):
    creador_d = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    donador = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    objeto = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    def whenpublished(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        
        diff = now - self.creation_date

        if diff.days == 0 and diff.seconds >= 0 and diff.seconds < 60:
            seconds= diff.seconds
            
            if seconds == 1:
                return "Hace " + str(seconds) +  " segundo"
            
            else:
                return "Hace " + str(seconds) +  " segundos"

            

        if diff.days == 0 and diff.seconds >= 60 and diff.seconds < 3600:
            minutes= math.floor(diff.seconds/60)

            if minutes == 1:
                return "Hace " + str(minutes) +  " segundo"
            
            else:
                return "Hace " + str(minutes) +  " minutos"



        if diff.days == 0 and diff.seconds >= 3600 and diff.seconds < 86400:
            hours= math.floor(diff.seconds/3600)

            if hours == 1:
                return "Hace " + str(hours) +  " hora"

            else:
                return "Hace " + str(hours) +  " horas"
```

There are some problems here.

1. `'+data.fields.whenpublished+'`: This value returns `undefined` and I don't know how to access it
2. This condition: `{% if '+data.fields.cantidad+' == 1 %}` it is intepreted as False, while `'+data.fields.cantidad+'` is actually one `1`
3. This condition: `{% if donacion.message != '' %}` it is intepreted as True even if `'+data.fields.message+'` == `''` And in that case it should be interpreted as False

In order for you to compare this ajax html I'll provide you with the one I usually use to render my posts via a `GET` method:

```
     <div class="post-box col-md-1">
          <div>
              <div>
                    {% if donacion.cantidad == 1 %}
                      <h3>{{donacion.donador}} </h3><text>te donó {{donacion.cantidad}} {{donacion.objeto}}.</text>
                    {% else %}
                    <h3>{{donacion.donador}} </h3><text>te donó {{donacion.cantidad}} {{donacion.objeto}}s.</text>
                    {% endif %}
                      <br>
                      <text>{{ donacion.whenpublished }}</text>
                      {% if donacion.message != '' %}
                      <hr>
                    <text>{{donacion.message}}</text>
                    {% endif %}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

views.py

```
def load_more(request):
    offset=int(request.POST['offset'])
    limit=2
    posts=Post.objects.all()[offset:limit+offset]
    totalData=Post.objects.count()
    data={}
    posts_json=serializers.serialize('json',posts)
    return JsonResponse(data={
        'posts':posts_json,
        'totalResult':totalData
    })
```

Comment: Share also your views.py. How is it handled on the server side?

Comment: done @NKSM it is shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `whenpublished` is a method of your **Model**.

And actually you don't need to use `serializer`.

Try to do it like that:

```
def load_more(request):
    offset = int(request.POST['offset'])
    limit = 2
    posts = Post.objects.all()[offset:limit+offset]
    totalData = Post.objects.count()
    posts_data = [{
        'cantidad': post.cantidad,
        'donador': post.donador,
        'whenpublished': post.whenpublished(),
        "message": post.message } for post in posts]
    return JsonResponse(data={
        'posts':posts_data,
        'totalResult':totalData
    })
```

And then in your AJAX success you can use `res.posts` instead of `var json_data = $.parseJSON(res.posts);`

Comment: @NicolasAgustin, in this case it was easier to use iteration because you need to call your model method. When you need only model fields you can also use `values` as example `queryset.values("message","donador", ...)`.

Comment: I managed to solve point 2 with an if condition on `views.py` and removing the if logic from the html, but how could I solve point 3? I have to remove that `<hr>`if the message is empty

Comment: @NicolasAgustin, but why are you trying to use django template tags in your javascript?

Comment: I thought it could work, but it turns out it doesnt. I  use django template tags to manage some logic via get method as you can see in my code. But i'm failing to replace that django logic from the 'load more' action. I have to remove that <hr>if the message is empty and don't know how.

Comment: @NicolasAgustin, you have to use **JavaScript** `if else`.

Answer (score 0):

Django will load the template and serve it on request, injecting new code won't do anything after the page has been served.

Usually, a separate API endpoint is made on the backend, and the frontend calls it and loads data asynchronously

In your case, you can use js to load data and inject HTML elements instead of "code"